# One else for multiple if conditions

Tags: python, if-statement, short-circuiting

I created some functions which return 1 if all went well and 0 if there was an error. Now, I need to execute each of these functions in a defined order and verify the return values. If one of them returns 0, I need to reboot immediately, without invoking any of the subsequent functions.

I intended to use multiple `if`s but with one `else`:

```
if function_1():
    if function_2():
        if function_3():
            print "Everything went well"
else:
    reboot()
```

but it does not work like I want: I want the `else` part to be executed right after any of these conditions fails, and now it is executed only if `function_1` fails.

Comment: Raise an exception inside the functions if there's an error; it will propagate all the way up, and if you catch it on the outer level, you can decide to reboot.

Comment: Do you want all the functions to always run, or do you want to immediately reboot if any of them fail?

Comment: Why is there a `[tag:linux]`? Do you you also want to know how to do the reboot in Python?

Comment: Sorry for the linux tag, it's just because I run the script in Linux. The script needs to stop if one function fails

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are two ways to do this.

1). You can use one `if` statement, and `and` the conditions together. This will produce "short circuiting" behavior, in that it will continue through the functions until the first one fails, then none of the remaining will execute.

```
if function_1() and function_2() and function_3():
    print "Everythings went well"
else:
    Reboot
```

2) If you want all to execute, here is a method, though it is more cumbersome.:

```
successful = True

successful = successful and function_1()
successful = successful and function_2()
successful = successful and function_2()

if successful:
    print "Everythings went well"
else:
    Reboot
```

Comment: This would work if you wanted the behavior of a short-circuit on any of the functions failing, but not if you need to gaurentee that each function is called.

Comment: Not sure why this got a downvote  - seems like this solutions is the same as the OPs - even with respect to the shortcutting.

Comment: That's certainly what I'd do. Not sure why the downvote.

Comment: If statements are not equivalent.

Comment: Someone has been following me around all morning and instantly downvoting everything I post by -1 :/ I'm not sure why.

Comment: If `function_1()` fails, the other functions won't be executed. This I think is not the intended behaviour.

Comment: The SO engine is pretty good at spotting that behaviour and reversing it.

Comment: Since the OP didn't post working code, you can't be sure if shortcutting is or isn't the desired behaviour.

Comment: @vaultah what is the difference? Why are they not equivalent ?

Comment: @fedorqui This is exactly what the code in the question does as well, so seems correct.

Comment: @Evert true. Let's see what the OP comments, because his words (not his code) says "I need to execute all this functions in a defined order and verify all functions"

Comment: @Evert but that is not what the OPs code segnment will do in any case - function_2() will only execute if function_1() returns True

Comment: @TonySuffolk66 Isn't that the case as well in the first example here, with the `and` shortcut? If `function_1()` returns False/0, `function_2()` won't be evaluated.

Comment: It's funny that people are downvoting and quibbling about the answer to an unclear question instead of downvoting the question and voting to close it as unclear.

Comment: Many thanks for this answer. The first solution is what I need. Sorry for the uncleared question, I need to execute all the function but each function is dependent to the previous. So if one fails, I need to stop everything. It was not clear, sorry for that.

Comment: You'd be better off using `all()` in the second snippet.

Answer (score 4):

It's possible to get the short-circuiting behaviour you want (jumping directly to the `else` clause as soon as any of your functions return `False`) in a more compact way with [`all()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all):

Let's set up some dummy functions for demonstration purposes:

```
def function_1():
    print("first")
    return True

def function_2():
    print("second")
    return False

def function_3():
    print("third")
    return True
```

... now, with this code:

```
functions = [function_1, function_2, function_3]

if all(f() for f in functions):
    print("all good")
else:
    print("oh no!")
```

... we get this output:

```
first
second
oh no!
```

Answer (score 2):

You could make a list:

```
functions = [function_1(), function_2(), function_3()]
```

then check all of them:

```
if all(functions):
    print 'OK'
else:
    Reboot
```

This way you're running all the functions (assuming this is a requirement), and checking whether all are true.

Assuming all the functions pass:

```
In [1]: functions = [True, True, True]

In [2]: all(functions)
Out[2]: True
```

Or if one fails:

```
In [3]: functions = [True, True, False]

In [4]: all(functions)
Out[4]: False
```

Comment: Why are you calling the first two, and not the third?  If you invoke the functions when building the tuple, they will all execute regardless of the results or previous functions.  If not, you need a little more work to call them.

Comment: @WilliamPursell Whoops - a typo! Cheers GreenAsJade

Comment: @Cyber No, but executing them all and storing the results in a list will (which this does)

Comment: Better change it to a generator: `functions = (f() for f in (function_1, function_2, function_3))`

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary You could do, but it adds a bit of complexity. I'm assuming OP is unfamiliar with Python, so I'm trying to keep it really simple

Comment: @AlexL: but the difference is *crucial*. Ashwini's version only calls the functions *as long as they continue to be successful*. Yours calls them all up-front.